# Create a server HTTP client from scratch w/Java

Tags: java, sockets, http

I have an assignment where

"The objective of this assignment is to practice network programming and learn about applica-
tion layer protocols. Specifically, you will implement an `HTTP client` program to download web
objects from various web servers on the Internet"

I cannot use `URL class` or `URLConnection` class.  So this makes it a little harder.

I know that the steps to create a connection would be to create a Socket and then connect to the URL and use a Buffered I/O stream to communicate with the server.

I've been looking for examples online but all use `URL` and `URLConnection classes`.

So My thought process is

1. Create Socket - bind it to the `url + port 80` (I found that port 80 is for http requests? Could be wrong)
2. Create `I/O stream` to socket
3. Handshaking (I don't know exactly how this works yet)
4. Request Download
5. Cache

Is my thought process correct?  And also how to I implement downloading lets say an image from the Server once I get a proper response?

Comment: Did you know you can manually act as an HTTP client (requester) by using telnet?

Comment: @NayukiMinase -  I don't even really know what telnet is  - but I know for this particular assignment we have to run past him any extra libraries we want to use.  And after a bit of research this may be something he may not allow me to use.  But I will ask, and also look into telnet further.

Comment: telnet is a command-line program to let you connect to a server. It is not a library; we are using it as a learning tool. You type text, and the server responds with text. HTTP is a text-based protocol, and you can basically run it by hand and get a reasonable response.

Comment: I just typed these 4 lines into my shell/command window: `telnet www.orf.at 80` `GET /stories/2302090/ HTTP/1.0` `User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0`   `[empty line]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on what actually gets sent in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP): https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/

> Sample HTTP Exchange
>
> To retrieve the file at the URL
>
> ```
> http://www.somehost.com/path/file.html
> ```
>
> first open a socket to the host www.somehost.com, port 80 (use the default port of 80 because none is specified in the URL). Then, send something like the following through the socket:
>
> ```
> GET /path/file.html HTTP/1.0
> From: someuser@jmarshall.com
> User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
> [blank line here]
> ```
>
> The server should respond with something like the following, sent back through the same socket:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.0 200 OK
> Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Content-Length: 1354
>
> <html>
> <body>
> <h1>Happy New Millennium!</h1>
> (more file contents)
>   .
>   .
>   .
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> After sending the response, the server closes the socket.

Comment: Thank you for this response, going to look into this and test it all out and report back my success tomorrow.